# how to add activex in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i used angular6+typescript on vscode.the broswer is IE11.

My code is written on app.component.html and can't run.

the html code is:

```
<div>
  <div >
    <object ID="activexFirst" CLASSID="CLSID:xxxxx-xxx" width="300" height="200"></object>
  </div>
  <div>
    <object ID="activeSencod" classid="CLSID:xxxxx-xxx" width="600" height="500"></object>
  </div>
</div>
```

the app.component.ts code is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
//todo..
}
```

but it is write on Index.html is ok.
How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe angular-element different native html-element,now it's ok.
the app.component.ts code is:

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    ActiveX.SetActiveXHtml(this.tActive1Div);
  }
```

the ActiveX.ts is

```
public static SetActiveXHtml(activeXDiv: ElementRef): void {
        let obj = document.getElementById('simplename') as any;
        if (obj == null) {
            obj = document.createElement('object');
            obj.name = 'name';
            obj.id = 'name';
            obj.classid = 'CLSID:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        }
        const cloneObj = obj.cloneNode(true);
        activeXDiv.nativeElement.appendChild(cloneObj);
    }
```

cloneNode method is very very Important !!!